# Filter based on join table's fields in Sequel many_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby, sequel

Assuming:

- a `many_to_many` association defined in the many_to_many section of the [Sequel documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html); `artists --< albums_artists >-- albums`
- `albums_artists` has a `foo` field

How do I access the fields on the `albums_artists` table in a `WHERE` clause? This syntax doesn't work:

```
<% @artist.albums_dataset.where(:foo => 'bar').each do |album| %>
  ...
  <%= album[:foo] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If I were to add a model for `album_artists`, creating two associations in the process, would I remove the existing `many_to_many` association?

Comment: BTW, for some databases your syntax does work just fine (e.g. SQLite3). Next time you might mention (a) what RDBMS you're using, and (b) what error exactly you got. ("Doesn't work" is not clear.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to [qualify the table name](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html#label-Qualifying+identifiers+-28column-2Ftable+names-29) for the column you want to access, using the syntax `:tablename__columnname` (two underscores).

```
@artist.albums_dataset.filter(:albums_artists__foo => "bar").each do |album|
```

Here's a test, also showing the generated SQL:

```
require 'sequel'; DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table(:artists){ primary_key :id; String :name }
DB.create_table(:albums){ primary_key :id; String :name }
DB.create_table(:albums_artists) do
  String :foo
  foreign_key :artist_id, :artists
  foreign_key :album_id, :albums
  primary_key [:artist_id, :album_id]
end

class Artist < Sequel::Model; many_to_many :albums;  end
class Album  < Sequel::Model; many_to_many :artists; end

Artist.multi_insert [ {name:"Bob"}, {name:"Dylan"}, {name:"Joni"} ]
Album.multi_insert [ {name:"BobSolo"}, {name:"JoniSolo"},
                     {name:"BobJoni"}, {name:"BobDylan"},
                     {name:"BobJoniDylan"} ]

# If the album name includes the artist, add them to it.
Artist.each do |ar| Album.each do |al|
  if al.name.include?(ar.name)
    DB[:albums_artists] << {artist_id:ar.id, album_id:al.id}
  end
end end

bob.albums.map(&:name)
#=> ["BobSolo", "BobJoni", "BobDylan", "BobJoniDylan"]

bob.albums_dataset.filter(albums_artists__foo:"bar").sql
#=> SELECT `albums`.*
#=>   FROM `albums` INNER JOIN `albums_artists`
#=>   ON (`albums_artists`.`album_id` = `albums`.`id`)
#=>   WHERE ((`albums_artists`.`artist_id` = 1)
#=>     AND  (`albums_artists`.`foo` = 'bar'))

bob.albums_dataset.filter(albums_artists__foo:"bar").all
#=> [#<Album @values={:id=>5, :name=>"BobJoniDylan"}>]
```